# Oracle select selected columns from a table whose column names are available in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me give an example :

Suppose I have a table `TableA(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)`

I have another table TableB where their are entries of the names of the columns of TableA that required to be fetched, for example `Col2 and Col5`

Now I want to write an SQL query that will only fetch the columns of TableA as defined in TableB .

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic sql to get this, if you want your query to be based on column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start.

The idea is to build a concatenated list of column_names as a varchar

```
'col1, col2, col3, col4'
```

and to use it in a dynamic sql query.

```
declare 
column_list xmltype;
column_names varchar(10000);

begin

SELECT 
          XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, t1.column_name || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()')
          column_name
  into column_list
  FROM all_tab_cols t1
  where t1.table_name = 'TABLEA'
  and exists (select null 
              from TableB
              where t1.column_name = <the field for the column_name in tableB>);

column_names := RTRIM(column_list.getClobVal(), ',');

--this will just display the sql query, you'll need to execute it to get your results with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
dbms_output.put_line( 'SELECT '||column_names||' from TableA');
end;
```